# Python android application connection

Tags: python, android, android-studio, database-connection, project

I have build a an app using android studio and a python script on my laptop for face detection but now i want to run that python program by clicking a button on my android app

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for an API.

You can implement this in several ways but I recommend you to make a HTTP API.

Checkout flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

```py
@app.route('/face-detection')
def face_detection():
    ...
    # call your script functionality
    ...
    return response
```

Your app should make something like

button.onclick -> HTTP REQUEST to your Laptop:api_port /face-detection

Have a nice day!